# What does "no method return value" mean in Eclipse Debug perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse

Placing a breakpoint in a method which is run by multiple threads, I encountered for the first time a "no method return value" `Name` in the Variables tab:

[image: no method return value]

What does it mean?

Acting, breakpoints in other places behave normally and do not produce this message.
Why am I seeing this?

---

**UPDATE:**
I found the answer for *"Why I am seeing this?"*:

As I clarified in the comment below, the aforementioned method *does* return a value. However, it is static and despite *clean build* of the entire project building it, I could not get rid of that weird "no method return value" thing.

Only after I did **clean build** of **all projects** in my workspace, did this message disappear and was replaced by the normal variables names and values display.

Any answer that could explain *why* an entire workspace *clean build* is mandated and why "no method return value" instead of some other (more descriptive) message, will be accepted.

Comment: Normally Eclipse would show the value returned by that function call, but it has none.

Comment: @tobias_k Weird. That method in which I placed a breakpoint *does* return a value (int), but for some reason, I am unable to view any of the variables in that method (I can only view `this`). Could this be related to the fact that this method is being called by numerous threads running concurrently?

Comment: The _Variables_ view shows the variable of the in the _Debug_ view selected stack trace item. Different threads have different stack traces which are shown as separate subtrees in the _Debug_ view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **return value** is displayed **when you step over the end of a non-void method.**

For example, when the debugger stops at a breakpoint there is no method return value:

[image]

but when you step over the end of the method via ***Step Return*** (<kbd>F7</kbd>) or at the end of a method via *Step Over* (<kbd>F6</kbd>), the method return value is shown:

[image]