# How can I remove "no method return value" from debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have a plug-in and I need to extract all variables from Java Stack Frame. However, when I get all of them, the first one says "no method return value".

I thought it cloud be because of my method did no return any value. But, although my method returns whatever, I keep retrieving this value.

Moreover, when a program or algorithm is debugged as a Java Project (not plug-in), this value keeps showing.

I leave a post in which this question is commented: [What does "no method return value" mean in Eclipse Debug perspective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259531/what-does-no-method-return-value-mean-in-eclipse-debug-perspective). However, there is no solution for this problem.

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to your question [when a method return value is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55935023/6505250).

The displaying of the method return value can be deactivated in ***Window > Preferences: Java > Debug*** by unchecking the checkbox ***Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow)***.